# Dark lines on object from SAO in ThreeJs

Tags: three.js

Since I update ThreeJs in r153 my object has dark line when SOS is enable.

With SOA enabled:

[image]:

Without SOA :

[image]

Any idea on how I can remove these lines ?

Comment: The upcoming release `r156` contains a fix for `SAOPass`. Can you please try it? `r156` should be available in the next days.

Comment: Nice to hear, as soon as the version would be released I will update it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The r156 has solved the issue.